# What is the fastest way of testing correctness of a sorting function?

Tags: arrays, performance, sorting, testing, correctness

Using a genetic algorithm, I found this comparison list:

```
compareAndSwap(x[0],x[2]);
compareAndSwap(x[3],x[4]);
compareAndSwap(x[2],x[4]);
compareAndSwap(x[0],x[3]);
compareAndSwap(x[2],x[3]);
compareAndSwap(x[1],x[3]);
compareAndSwap(x[1],x[2]);
compareAndSwap(x[0],x[1]);
compareAndSwap(x[3],x[4]);
```

but I need to test it if it works for all cases. Also number of array elements(currently 5) can grow up to 100 in some situations. This would mean that number of cases to check against is growing fast like more than `pow(2,100)`.

If I give an oppositely sorted array alone as a worst case, that doesn't check against any error about middle element `x[2]` comparisons. For example, 5,4,3,2,1 is sorted by some function into 1,2,3,4,5, by

```
compareAndSwap(x[0],x[4]);
compareAndSwap(x[1],x[3]);
```

alone and this certainly doesn't sort many cases of 5-element arrays.

Tried random number generators for sample arrays but not sure if its acceptable:

```
      std::random_device rd;
      std::mt19937 rng(rd());
      std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,1);

      for(int k=0;k<500;k++)
      {
        std::vector<double> arraySorted;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            arraySorted.push_back(dist(rng));

      //sortNetwork(arraySorted.data());

      //if(!std::is_sorted(arraySorted.begin(),arraySorted.end())) 
            throw std::runtime_error("error");
      }
```

even this can still miss some parts. Is there a fast way to test sorting algorithms?

What if it was 1000 elements array? Are these tested using math, pen and paper within some theorems and known algorithms or using supercomputers?

Just some sample cases for 4 elements:

```
1 2 3 4   
1 2 4 3   
2 1 3 4    
2 1 4 3   
1 2 0 1                        
1 2 1 0                         
2 1 0 1
2 1 1 0
3 4 2 1                           
3 4 1 2
4 3 2 1
4 3 1 2
1 1 1 1
```

seems to have more than pow(2,n) cases.

Can a sorting network be treated like a graph problem when generating test data, somehow?

Comment: Can you prove that it works for some case of *n* elements and then prove by induction that it works for *n + 1* elements?

Comment: Do you mean that I should test with 2 elements then 3 elements then 4 .... until time limit exceeded and accept algorithm as "works"? I couldn't understand "induction" part. Is it something like using an n=2 sorter to test an n=3 sorter? How? Or is it about testing correctness of the algorithm that produces sorting network?

Comment: Proof by induction is an established method: [Mathematical induction](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/mathematical-induction.html).

Comment: Then its about algorithm that generates sorting function. I'll try that way, thank you. What if method contains randomness and can changes its behavior time to time so that I can feel unsafe when looking at 1000 element sorter?

Comment: Surely the compareAndSwap is used in a binary sorting algorithm. I believe that is the one you need to test and not all your pow (2,n) cases?

Comment: The number of [permutations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html) is ***n!***. So testing every permutation is not tractable for a large *n*. Is your *compareAndSwap* code generated or manually written for each *n*?

Comment: @rustyx it is generated code.

Comment: @rustyx - since this is a sorting network, he may be using the [zero one principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Zero-one_principle), which reduces the number of cases to (2^n). However I'm not aware of sorting networks much beyond n = 17. If the code and system are fast enough, you can probably test up to 12! or 2^32 to 2^34 cases in a reasonable time.

Comment: @rcgldr zero one principle seems good up to around 10-15 as you say but n=1000 is like a dream only. Maybe quantum computing can do that? Also answer below says I'm not wrong as long as I'm not forced to prove it and able to respond to any user-producible error.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik - it's sorting networks that have only been optimized for up to about 17 or so. Zero one principle should be good for 32 to 34 or so, but I don't know if any sorting networks go up to 32 or 34. Instead of a true sorting network, you could consider using a standard compare and swap based sort algorithm, such as bubble sort or insertion sort, but these have O(n^2) time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *could* check every single iteration of every single possible list, as you've pointed out this would be far too slow. Testing is not about [proving the algorithm correct](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Correctness_(computer_science)), for that you'd need to do a proof. Testing is about reducing the possibility of a bug by testing all the places it might hide. Testing rarely attempts to cover the entire possible space, but rather possible *types* of errors.

Here's some examples to exercise a sort function.

- An empty list
- A single element list
- A list with all zeros
- An ordered list
- A reversed list
- A list of all the same elements
- A very large list
- A list with strange elements (for example, Unicode, negative numbers, overloaded numbers)

Then there's erroneous inputs which should return an error rather than garbage. Garbage in, error out.

- A null pointer
- A list of nulls
- A list which is too large (if your function has size limits)

And yes, randomize. Generate random valid lists of random valid sizes and then verify the result of the sort is in order. This helps cover any cases you might have missed and avoids any bad assumptions you may have made. This is particularly important when testing a function ["black box"](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Black-box_testing) meaning the tester has no knowledge of its internals. Every time you run more random lists against the function you further reduce the possibility there is a bug.

Be sure to output the random seed used so you can repeat the test if there is a failure.

Finally, use [test coverage](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Code_coverage) to ensure your tests are hitting all lines and branches of the code. The code might be generated by an AI, but you can still do a coverage analysis on it to identify your testing gaps. Running a code beautifier over the probably unreadable AI generated code will help your understanding of where your need more tests.

Comment: Then I take pen&paper and do some calculus to find it out. Maybe by following probabilities of compare results or something like that. Thank you.